# Why my ImageButton does not update dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to build a checkers game using `Asp.Net`.

I am using a system that updates `ImageButton` to show the state of the board(playing by clicking on an piece and then the destination).
My update works if I'm using the original board but it doesn't show any updates.

I know the board is changed when the function checks it. I can't seem to find the problem.

The console is showing the intended result.

```
protected void Update()
{
   string  red = "photo/checkers/checkers-red.png",
           black = "photo/checkers/checkers-black.png",
           empty = "photo/checkers/Cempty.png";
   Button place = (Button)Session["place"];
   char[,] board = (char[,])Session["board"];
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
       {
           char letter = (char)('A' + i);
           string ID = letter + "" + j;
           ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton)place.Parent.FindControl(ID);
           imgBtn.ImageUrl = (IsRorB(board[i, j]) ? board[i, j] == 'r' ? red : black : empty);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(board[i, j]);
       }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
   }
   //LblEror.Text = board[2, 7].ToString();
   // LblEror.Text = IsRorB(board[2, 7]).ToString();
   // ImageButton imgBtn1 = (ImageButton)place.Parent.FindControl("c7");
   // imgBtn1.ImageUrl = empty;
}

protected bool IsRorB(char c)//check if a place is filled or empty
{
   if (c == 'r' || c == 'b')
   {
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: When you debug, does the code you're showing produce the expected result?  Perhaps the problem is elsewhere?  For example, in WebForms it's a very common mistake to have code in `Page_Load` which overwrites changes intended in event handlers.  This would be a good opportunity to create the simplest possible *complete* example of the problem to demonstrate.

Comment: When i debug the code seem to work fine as far as i could see the code works the first time when its resetting the board but after that it just wont update the pieces. I have some code in page_load but its under if (!IsPostBack).

Comment: My mistake, I delete my answer - and think it again, you make something other than I understand at first

Comment: storing a WebControl in the Session looks a bit suspicious. doesn't the referenced "place.Parent" have a unique ID, or a simpler way to identify?

Comment: yes thank you so much the fact that i stored the controls in the session is what caused it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did not work because the controls were stored in the session

```
 Button place = (Button)Session["place"];
```